# PageSetup.PrintArea for multiple ranges that are separated

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have the following code that exports the selected range in the worksheet as .pdf file:

```
    'More coding above
    With Sheet7
        If (CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = True) Then
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A8:M80"
        ElseIf (CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = False) Then
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A8:M55"
        ElseIf (CheckBox1.Value = False And CheckBox2.Value = True) Then
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A8:M32, A56:M80"
        Else
            MsgBox 'At least one option must be selected!'
            Exit Sub
        End If
     End With
     'More coding below
```

However, when only `CheckBox2` is checked, the file is generated selecting only the areas as set by `If/Else`, but still showing the `A33:M55` gap between ranges.

Is there anyway I could suppress this gap? I want the code to print both ranges as if they were one.

I tried the `Union` method, but it gives me the same result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're using `PrintArea`, then each comma you use to separate ranges will put those ranges onto a separate page. You can either hide the ranges you don't want while you print or copy the ranges to a temporary sheet, print, and delete the sheet like so https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win008.htm

Comment: Hadn't thought of those alternatives, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to hide unnecesarry rows if it's possible for a moment before print to PDF. In this way you should make sure after macro all rows are visible (additional you can use On Error GoTo and unhide just in case)

Comment: Your answer could use more... answer. Maybe give a small example of vba that will hide the ranges that OP mentioned in their initial post

Comment: I cannot give example because in this method you must hide rows in printing macro, not in this one posted above. I am pretty sure that the author know how to hide rows "Sheet7.Rows("33:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True"